# Detect HtmlLoad Error

Tags: air

Is there a way to trigger an Error Event when HtmlLoader.load() fails?

When there is no internet connection, the COMPLETE Event never gets triggered. I want to be able to tell the user "there is no connection, close the current window and do someting else."

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you have to listen instance of URLRequest for some events

```
        //your code to load page in to HtmlLoader
        var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/");
        configureListeners(urlReq);
        html.width = stage.stageWidth;
        html.height = stage.stageHeight;
        html.load(urlReq); 
        addChild(html);

     //add all listeners you need
     private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
   dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,securityErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I am getting the followng error: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeEventListener through a reference with static type flash.net:URLRequest.

Comment: Why can't I use removeEventListener? I want to remove the listener as soon as the IO_ERROR function is called.

Comment: Now, even without using removeEventListener I am getting this error: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type flash.net:URLRequest.

Answer (score -1):

This code is working fine For Flex 4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/");
            configureListeners(html);
            html.width = 800;
            html.height = 800;
            html.load(urlReq); 
            conteiner.addChild(html);

        }

        //add all listeners you need
        private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void 
                   {
dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,securityErrorHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        }

        .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:SpriteVisualElement id="conteiner">

</s:SpriteVisualElement>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: But the htmlloader class does not have an IO_ERROR Event. See adobe document for reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html

Comment: Try add listeners to html.loaderInfo - it should has all events you need http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html